# Any library supports Guava tables to csv format?

Tags: java, csv, guava

Are there any library supports Guava tables to csv format?
I generated

```
RowSortedTable<String, String, Double> graph
```

But the generating process takes some time(some query processing is needed), so I want to save this intermediate result and want to read and use it again.

Comment: Apparently no built-in support for CSV serialization yet exists, even though [it has been requested](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/813).

Comment: Solved this problem by using openCSV library. Thank you for all answers

Comment: @SUNDONG can you please post your solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @sinapan Since the post is outdated, I couldn't remember the solution. Please refer to other answers, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html):

```
final RowSortedTable<String, String, Double> graph = TreeBasedTable.create();

graph.put("A", "0", 0.0);
graph.put("A", "1", 1.0);
graph.put("B", "0", 0.1);
graph.put("B", "1", 1.1);

final Appendable out = new StringBuilder();
try {
    final CSVPrinter printer = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.print(out);

    printer.printRecords(//
            graph.rowMap().values()//
                    .stream()//
                    .map(x -> x.values())//
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));

} catch (final IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(out);
// 0.0,1.0
// 0.1,1.1
```

Comment: this skips the first column though

Answer (score -3):

To create a CSV file using Guava you can use [Joiner](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html).

```
  Joiner.on(",").join(yourStrings)
```

Try to drop the output of this utility into a file whith extension CSV.

Comment: `Joiner.join` expects an `Iterable`, which I believe a Guava `Table` is not. You would need to retrieve a _view_ to the table cells and pass that to `join`. In any case, all of the elements would be output on the same row.

Comment: CSVs aren't quite this trivial. You need to handle escaping.